# Aligning logo image with navigation bar

Tags: html, css

I would like to align logo image with navigation bar so that logo is on left and navigation bar at the center. You can see here what I have tried: http://jsfiddle.net/4fTwh/

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class="navigation">
        <p> <img class="logo-img" src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/tatice/browsers/128/Google-Chrome-icon.png" alt="Logo">
            <ul id="nav-list">
                <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="">News</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
                <li><a href="">About</a></li>
            </ul>
        </p>        
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
.navigation{
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #CEE3F6; 
}

#nav-list{
   list-style-type: none;
}

#nav-list li{
   display: inline;
   font-size: 18px;
   margin: 20px;
}
.logo-img{
    float: left;
    margin: 0px 15px 15px 0px;
}
```

Now, I would like for navigation bar text to be bottom aligned with logo image. And also that colored background to be height of the image (not lower around navigation bar text, as it is now). So basically, how to wrap together logo(on left) and navigation bar(centered) so that background is height of higher of these two elements?

Comment: What about the height of navigation bar..? and the size of image..? the original image seems to be too small.

Comment: @TilwinJoy well, image is higher than content of navigation bar (or just suppose it is), so the background(colored) should be high as image height

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this: [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/4fTwh/9/)

```
.navigation {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #CEE3F6;
    vertical-align:bottom;
    line-height:120px;
    height:120px;
}

#nav-list li {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin: 20px;
    vertical-align:bottom;
    line-height:normal;   
}

.logo-img {
    position:absolute;
    left:10px;
    top:10px;
    margin: 0px 15px 15px 0px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, although other answer are also helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You looking for something like this?

```
#nav-list{
   list-style-type: none;
   background: url('http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/tatice/browsers/128/Google-Chrome-icon.png') no-repeat;
padding: 102px 0 0 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4fTwh/2/

Comment: I need image to be inside html page, not in styling

Comment: @Vladimir Been on holiday for a week, apologies for the late reply. You can have a div with an inline style on the HTML page instead of having it in the CSS. For background only.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/4fTwh/7/)

```
.logo{
    display:inline-block;
    float:left
}
#nav-list{
    margin-top:55px;
    list-style-type: none;
    float:left; display:inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your HTML I would remove the `<p>` tag. It doesn't add any value here.

You CSS is almost there. Below are the alterations I made to it.

```
.navigation{
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #CEE3F6; 
  overflow: hidden /* This Allows for the Background to span the entire height */
}

#nav-list{
  list-style-type: none;
  float: left; /* Keeps the elements side by side*/
  margin-bottom: 0 /* fix the spacing to allow the menu to be at the bottom */
}

#nav-list li{
  float: left; /* allows the li tags to be side by side. */
  font-size: 18px;
  margin: 20px 20px 0 0; /* Fixed a little of the spacing, etc. */
  padding:69px 0 0 0 /* Moved the LI down to be at the bottom*/
}

.logo-img{
  float: left;  
  margin: 0px 15px 0 0px; /* fixed the spacing. */
}
```

Here is the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9M84M/)